# Powershell Popup Buttons Restartscript

Tags: powershell

I just started with powershell and created a popup script and want that the two Buttons do something. For exmaple one of them should restart the computer and the other one says 'Ask me in 60 Minutes again' so i want to do a little loop and run the script in 60 Minutes once more.
I have this right know but the restart did not work and i'm not sure how to do the loop, maybe someone can help me...

```
If ($WPFMessageBoxOutput -eq "Restart")
{
    Restart-Computer
}
ElseIf ($WPFMessageBoxOutput -eq "Ask in 60 Minutes again")
{
    Do Something..
}
```

Comment: Where did `$WPFMessageBoxOutput` come from? Can you show us the code that assigns a value to that variable? Also, is this being run from inside a loop?

Comment: $Button.Add_Click( {
New-Variable -Name WPFMessageBoxOutput -Value $($This.Content.Text) -Option ReadOnly -Scope Script -Force
$Window.Close()

Comment: Not sure if it's the right one

Comment: Don't **create** a new variable inside the Click event handler. Instead, define it somewhere earlier in your form code with a value of `$null`, `[string]::Empty` or `''`. Inside that click event, set its value by referring to it as `$script:WPFMessageBoxOutput`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. 

And can someone please tell me what command i can use to run the script again after a button is pressed?